# Rotate view by touch android

Tags: java, android

Rotate view by touch android  Rotate layout on touch but the strange thing happens when I press on number one and rotate with my finger. It working on but when I press on other location like number2 or number3 or number4 or any other circle number1 circle come below my finger why !!

I want to catch any circle and rotate the shape from it 
in another way, I want to rotate the shape from where I touched not form only

[image]

number one it I tried many codes and can't find the solution

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.github.andreilisun.circular_layout.CircularLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTouchListener{
    private RelativeLayout wheel;
    private CircularLayout circle;
    TextView number1TextView,number2TextView;
    private double mCurrAngle = 0 ,mPrevAngle = 0;
    ArrayList<View>views;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wheel = findViewById(R.id.rl_main_layout);
        circle = findViewById(R.id.cl_main_layout);
        number1TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_main_number1);
        number2TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_main_number2);
        views = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<circle.getChildCount(); i++){
            views.add(circle.getChildAt(i));
        }
        wheel.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final float xc = wheel.getWidth() / 2;
        final float yc = wheel.getHeight() / 2;

        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                System.out.println("MOVe "+mCurrAngle);

                mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
                mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
                animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0);
                for(int i=0; i<views.size(); i++) {
                  //  if(views.get(i) instanceof TextView)
                    //animate2(-mCurrAngle, -mPrevAngle, 0, views.get(i));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void animate(double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long durationMillis ) {
        final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) fromDegrees, (float) toDegrees,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(durationMillis);
        rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);
        wheel.startAnimation(rotate);
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:gravity="center">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp200w"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp200w"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <com.github.andreilisun.circular_layout.CircularLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp270w"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp270w"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp70w"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10h"
          >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_main_number1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Number1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp70w"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10h"
            >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main_number2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
             />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
             />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main_tefa"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEfa"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
              />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number6"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
             />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number7"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
              />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60w"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp2w"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Number8"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
             />

    </com.github.andreilisun.circular_layout.CircularLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle your calculating for rotation is with respect to the image as a whole.  You need to save the angle you originally touch the image at, and rotate it with respect to that original angle.

Although really the entire way you're doing this is wrong.  You're using a 0 ms animation?  You should just be setting a rotation matrix on the view.

Comment: I have a similar issue can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556955/how-to-rotate-a-view-in-android-and-also-adjust-its-height-in-respect-to-parent) @GabeSechan